# querying (select statement) on a view in hibernate

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i want to display result of select statement on a already existing VIEW. but i keep getting the below error that table is not found and trying to create table:

```
22058 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - Default entity-mode: pojo
24051 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata  - table not found: MGSMS
24675 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata  - table not found: MGSMS
24675 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - create table MGSMS (ID number(10,0) not null, DEST varchar2(255 char), MESSAGE varchar2(255 char), primary key (ID))
25969 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: create table MGSMS (ID number(10,0) not null, DEST varchar2(255 char), MESSAGE varchar2(255 char), primary key (ID))
25970 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

i am new to hibernate. Can anyone please help.

i have dbInfo.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="com.javaHb.queryDBhb.dbInfo" table="MGSMS" >  
    <id column="ID" name="id" type="int">
      <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <property name="dest" type="string" column="DEST" /> 
    <property name="message" type="string" column="MESSAGE" />

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

main java classTakersQuery.java

```
package com.javaHb.queryDBhb;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TakersQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        //get few fields
        Query query = session.createQuery("select sms from MGSMS sms");
        List<Object[]> rows = query.list();

        for (Object[] row: rows) {
            System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
            System.out.println("dest: " + row[0]);
            System.out.println("message: " + row[1]);
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

DBInfo.java is the java class , i.e Persistent class

```
package com.javaHb.queryDBhb;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;  
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;  

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Loader;

@Entity
@Immutable
public class dbInfo {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="dest")
    private String dest; 
    @Column(name="message")
    private String message;

    public int getid() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setid(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    public String getdest() {  
        return dest;  
    }  
    public void setdest(String dest) {  
        this.dest = dest;  
    }  
    public String getmessage() {  
        return message;  
    }  
    public void setmessage(String message) {  
        this.message = message;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: why not createNativeQuery

Comment: So you map dest and message from the mgsms table (look at dbInfo.hbm.xml) and then you select the sms column from this table `select sms from MGSMS sms`. The problems you have are: 1. The user that hibernate uses, can't see the mgsms table (another schema no select grants etc.). Then, when you tryto create it, it says it exists (even though you can't see it), but the Database prevents the creation. 3. Your select query must me something either like `select sms.* from ...` or enumerate all the columns there ..

Comment: MGSMS should be a class (entity) that is mapped to the MGSMS view. Have you created this class? If yes, then shows us the code.

Comment: @dsp_user i have update the class in my question at the end

Comment: In this case use select sms from dbInfo because dbInfo is the entity mapped to the MGSMS view.

Comment: Also, I don't sms in your entity. I see message but it's mapped to the message column, not the sms column. Check your field mappings.

Answer (score 0):

i had to correct the column mapping and it worked